# Lock to launcher/Pin to taskbar in Debian Wheezy/Gnome (was possible in Squeeze)

Tags: debian, gnome

In Debian Squeeze, if I right clicked on something in the Applications menu I could lock it to the top bar. I upgraded to Debian Wheezy and now if I right click it just opens the program. I'm using Virtualbox, so maybe the right click just isn't working. I also said "debian gnome" because it looks different than the regular gnome I know.

So how can I create shortcuts in gnome 3/debian wheezy? I don't care if it's pinning it to the "top bar", or locking it in the "task bar" (bottom). And while I'm at it, is there a way I can get a shortcut to the desktop (preferably a button, which I had in Debian squeeze). I've googled for all sorts of combinations of "debian (or gnome) shortcut to desktop" and "debian (or gnome) pin to taskbar"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key together with the right-mouse.

On applications that should give you the possibility to *Move/Remove*. On the open area of the taskbar in *Add to Panel…*

Comment: Awesome thanks! (right click on the top bar was what I wanted)

Comment: Oh any idea how to do this in Fedora (vanilla gnome if I'm not mistaken)?

Comment: No, haven't used RedHat for over 10 years.